# OS Architecture Determination in Windows using Delphi TOSVersion.TArchitecture

Tags: delphi

I am having one form with one TEdit and one TButton. I am trying to determine OS Architecture. So I have defined the following codes as suggested by Embarcadero forum :

```
function OSArchitectureToStr(const a: TOSVersion.TArchitecture): string;
function OSPlatformToStr(const p: TOSVersion.TPlatform): string;
function PlatformFromPointer: integer;
.
.
.
.
.

function OSArchitectureToStr(const a: TOSVersion.TArchitecture): string;
begin
  case a of
    arIntelX86: Result := 'Intel X86';
    arIntelX64: Result := 'Intel X64';
    else
      Result := 'UNKNOWN OS Aarchitecture';
  end;
end;

function OSPlatformToStr(const p: TOSVersion.TPlatform): string;
begin
  case p of
    pfWindows: Result := 'Windows';
    pfMacOS: Result := 'MacOS';
    else
      Result := 'UNKNOWN OS Platform';
  end;
end;

function PlatformFromPointer: integer;
begin
  Result := SizeOf(Pointer) * 8;
end;
.
.
.
.
.
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := OSPlatformToStr(TOSVersion.Platform) + ' ' + IntToStr(PlatformFromPointer) + ' Bit';
end;
```

But the problem is that It results always 32Bit OS though it is 64Bit OS. Please help me.

Comment: (First, this question has nothing to do with edits and buttons. It is always good practice to remove all irrelevant parts in your code before posting a question.) Second, you never use `OSArchitectureToStr`. Obviously your code is 32-bit, since `SizeOf(Pointer) = 4`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It should be possible to determine if the OS is 64 bit, even from a 32 bit application. I would even dare to say that you wouldn't have to check at all if your application itself is a 64 bit application. ;) But I agree that getting the size of a pointer isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You (erroneously!) use the following to get the architecture:

```
function PlatformFromPointer: integer;
begin
  Result := SizeOf(Pointer) * 8;
end;
```

Now, in a 32-bit application, `SizeOf(Pointer)` equals `4`, while in a 64-bit application, it equals `8`. So this only examines what type of application *you* are writing, not what OS it is running on! (So, obviously, your application is 32-bit. And that has nothing to do with the OS being 32-bit or 64-bit.)

You probably want to investigate `TOSVersion.Architecture` instead. But you don't. In fact, you never use it (or `OSArchitectureToStr`!) at all.

What you want is `OSArchitectureToStr(TOSVersion.Architecture)`.

Comment: Your concept is wrong. I have practically checked for both the cases SizeOf(Pointer) equals 4.

Comment: @Rubi: Although I have never used a 64-bit version of Delphi myself, that doesn't sound right. David?

Comment: @RubiHalder In a 32 bit process `SizeOf(Pointer)` is 4. It doesn't matter what architecture the OS has. A 32 bit process running on a 64 bit OS still has 32 bit pointers. If you compile to target 64 bit then pointers will be 64 bits wide, `SizeOf(Pointer)` would be 8. But your process is 32 bit and so it matters not one jot where you run it, `SizeOf(Pointer)` is 4. Indeed `SizeOf(Pointer)` is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @David: Thank you for verifying that I'm not wrong. [I got the impression that Rubi had 'verified' that `SizeOf(Pointer) = 4` even in a 64-bit application (otherwise, I couldn't see how my 'concept' was wrong).]

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain an application (process) in 32-bit and / or 64-bit version, you need to add the appropriate compiler to the project in the project.
In the * .dproj - Project window, select the Target Platforms item and add Windows 64-bit (of course you must have the option installed)
Now you can set target platform to 32-bit or 64-bit